# How to find magnetization of permanent magnet using its residual magnetization?

Tags: electromagnetism, magnetic-fields, magnetic-moment

I have a magnet with N52 designation whose remanence/residual magnetization $B_r = 1.4 T$. Magnet has dimension $50\times 20\times 5\text{ mm}$. **My question is how to find magnet`s magnetization $\vec{M}$ using these parameters?**

My approach so far has been finding magnetic dipole moment using formula from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magnetic_moment):

$$\vec{m} = \frac{1}{\mu}\vec{B_r}V$$

where $V$ is the volume of the magnet and $\vec{B_r}$ is the residual flux density or [remanence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Remanence). I struggle to convert this magnetic dipole moment to magnetization $\vec{M}$. Is this the correct approach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I recall, the magnetization is the dipole moment / unit volume. Divide your formula by V.